# VS Code API get position of closing parenthesis

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I tried to look over the API reference but didn't find anything, but since this is my first attempt on creating an extension I decided to try to ask here: is there any API that given an open parenthesis position it gives me the position ot the matching closing parenthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenthesis (bracket) matching is implemented in [`textModel.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.37.1/src/vs/editor/common/model/textModel.ts#L1925), function `_matchBracket`.  It is exposed by [`bracketMatching.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/contrib/bracketMatching/bracketMatching.ts), which publishes commands `editor.action.jumpToBracket` and `editor.action.selectToBracket` that you can invoke using [`executeCommand`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#commands.executeCommand).  It does not publish any way to query the bracket info without changing the selections.

[VSCode Issue #7177: Expose bracket matching functionality to extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7177) asked for a query-only capability.  It was closed in November 2017 because it "will not be considered in the next 6-12 months".

So, if you want to query the matching bracket for an arbitrary position without changing any editor state, I think you have to save the current selections, move the cursor to the position of interest, invoke `jumpToBracket`, record where the cursor went, then restore the selections.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I need!